# Android Views - Make one view transparent to a view below

Tags: android, xml, layout, view, transparent

I am struggling with making one view's background transparent so that any areas on top view that are not drawn actually reveals the bottom view.

I have read several threads here about this, but whatever I try the top view is drawn in black.

Both bottom view and top view are inherited from the View base class and onDraw() is overridden and this is my layout.xml:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<com.domain.myapp.MyBottomView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mybottomview"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@drawable/bottom_image"/>

<com.domain.myapp.MyTopView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mytopview"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
</merge>
```

Anyone got any suggestions for me I would be extremely greatful!

Regards
/Dee

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android

Comment: This is actually interesting! It does make the activity transparent instead of the view but maybe I can use that instead and get an even better effect.

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

A resource is available here : http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html

Comment: Thanks! But unfortunately no luck.. Already set transparent background in xml and cacheColorHint (from the article) did not change anything either.

Comment: I found a solution so I'll share that instead.
The trick was to replace the <merge> in the layout.xml with <FrameLayout>. Why the <merge> does not work I have no idea (eclipse even suggest me to use <merge>!)